# Issues with running php after page part is loaded with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, load

I'm having a problem whereby vars that i have stated in an external php script aren't showing in part of a page that's being loaded in later, by jquery.

The simplified code:

index.php:

```
<?php
require_once "init.php";
?>
//the rest of the page is added here.
```

init.php

```
<?php
$test = 'foo';
?>
```

home.php

```
<?php
echo $test;
?>
```

When a div is clicked, jquery will use .load to add 'home.php' into the page.

The problem is that the $test var isn't showing, because the 'init.php' hasn't been run with 'home.php' on the page. Is there any way i can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the only solution is to include init.php in home.php

Othervise the variable will be undefined.

Comment: Adding "include 'init.php';" on home.php doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When Jquery requests the home.php file $test is no longer defined because index.php code has finished running and the result been sent to the client. You may want to look at [Sessions](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php)
if you wish to store a variable on the server after a page has ran.